# Oracle SQL conditional operator explanation

Tags: sql, oracle

Please, may I ask if anyone can explain more on the following oracle sql conditional operator please ?
I only have limited oracle sql knowledge that it exclude checking for Sat and sometime for Sunday. Thanks so much!

```
SELECT 
  DECODE(RTRIM(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'DAY')),
              'SATURDAY', 4,
              'SUNDAY', DECODE(SIGN(TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'HH24')) - 20), 0, 4,
                                                                              -1, 4, COUNT(*)),
              COUNT(*))
  FROM DUAL
```

Comment: what output you go so for?

Comment: Hi the above is built by others, I would like to change it to exclude the sql checking for Fri 11pm GMT to Sun , I.e. only check for mon to Fri , and for Fri can be stopped checking from 11pm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The decode is basically checking the day of the week and returns some magic number = 4, which seems to be some enumerator for status. Anyway, to add the Friday after 11 pm will be:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'DY') = 'FRI' AND EXTRACT(HOUR FROM CAST(SYSDATE AS TIMESTAMP)) >= 23 THEN 4
            WHEN TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'DY') = 'SAT'                                                         THEN 4
            WHEN TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'DY') = 'SUN' AND EXTRACT(HOUR FROM CAST(SYSDATE AS TIMESTAMP)) <= 20 THEN 4
       ELSE COUNT(*)
       END
  FROM dual;
```

P.S. if your decode is 3 lines, you probably need to replace it with `CASE`. Case can do anything the `DECODE` can and is more readable.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! Excellent detailed explanation !!

Comment: But please may I ask more for the above origin decode statement , so what are the 0,4 and -1,4 , does it mean checking if Sat then 4, otherwise 0, and for sun before 8pm , will return 4 otherwise -1? 
0, 4,
                                                                              -1, 4

Comment: The part "SIGN(TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'HH24')) - 20)" this is basically a check if the time is after 8 PM and there are 3 options - before pm = return COUNT(*) - thats a pass, 0 it's 8 PM = return 4 - that's a no pass, and -1, that's a no pass as well since it's past 8 PM. It's rather simple, but long decodes are confusing.